# Is the following a strong proof of $\frac{d}{dx} (\sin(x))$

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, proof-verification, alternative-proof

Let $y$ be a value such that $y=\sin(x)$. Then, by first principals of differentiation: $$\frac{\delta y}{\delta x} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(x+h)-\sin(x)}{h}$$ using the difference of angles identity, $\displaystyle \sin(A)-\sin(B)=2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)$, $$\frac{\delta y}{\delta x} = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2\cos\left(\frac{2x+h}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)}{h}$$ dividing top and bottom by $2$ yields, $$\frac{\delta y}{\delta x}=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\cos\left(\frac{2x+h}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{h}{2}\right)}{\frac{h}{2}}$$ from here, given that $\displaystyle \lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = 1$, when the limit is taken, since there is no reason to take the limit "piece by piece" the entire expression is reduced to $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \cos\left(\frac{2x}{2}\right) = \cos(x)$$ 
short question is, is this a strong proof? Or is there another, potentially more simple proof for this scenario?

Comment: It depends on where you got the trigonometric identity and $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta} = 1$ from. Was that proved without using the derivatives of sine and cosine?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): [Is the proof of the derivative of $\sin(x)$ circular?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2420474/is-the-proof-of-the-derivative-of-sinx-circular?)

Comment: I'm not sure if you're familiar with it, but the proof for $\lim_{\theta \to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}$ comes from a geometric inequality, concluded by the squeeze theorem. I.e. no, it doesn't relate at all to the derivates of sine or cosine

Comment: Related, yes, but not necessarily a duplicate, the question you added uses different steps, I'm interested specifically in this method @MartinR

Comment: That depends on where you start: With a *geometrical* definition or with an *analytical* (as an infinite series). – If you take that trigonometric identity and the limit for granted then your proof is fine.

Comment: How does it depend on where I start? If I present a geometric proof for the limit of sin theta divided by theta as theta approaches 0, would I have to stick to a geometric proof throughout the case above as well? @MartinR

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2319969/is-the-proof-of-lim-theta-to-0-frac-sin-theta-theta-1-in-some-high-s

Comment: Thank you @velutluna , thats exactly the proof I was referring to.